# 3.7 V Li-ion rechargeable battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nicd-battery

I have a rechargeable flashlight that uses 3 Li-ion 3.7 V batteries. This flashlight works great the light is extremely bright and adjustable. It's one of those flashlights that plug right into the outlet and when the power goes out the flashlight  lights up so you can use it during power failures, so basically it is always charging. lately when I use it the light is bright but the batteries don't seem to last very long.

It is a few years old but I really like the flashlight so I thought maybe the batteries have been charged so many times they are not as effective as they used to be. I went to buy new batteries for it and I find out that the  batteries that are in it were 5800 mAh, 5800 mAh, and 4200 mAh? To purchase new batteries do I need to purchase that exact same combination? Not surprisingly the batteries come sold in 2 and 4 packs and I need 3. If i put 3 4200 mAh or 3 5800 mAh what would that do?

I'm assuming the flashlight company did their research and product testing and came up with this combo for a very good reason. So I am of course going to purchase the same size batteries to replace. However I'm still curious as in my 50 years of living never actually seen any product that uses different sized batteries like this. So a couple questions why would a company decide to use different size batteries for their product and what would happen if you placed all 3 batteries the same size what kind of dangers are you looking at! My wife didn't even notice they were different mAh as I'm sure most people probably wouldn't so I'm assuming the company realizes this and it would not be a big deal one way or another, but it still begs to ask what if?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I recommend that you break your wall of text into logical paragraphs. It will make it more readable and you're much more likely to get good answers. The symbol for 'ampere' is 'A'.

Comment: Li-Ion batteries do not last long when they are always fully charged. my Li-Ion batteries last for years when they are at the storage and selling voltage of 3.7V each, then are fully charged to 4.2V each before each use.. I think that all three of your batteries should be Name-Brand and all be the same mAh.

Comment: If your batteries are connected in series it would make sense for them to all have the same capacity. What form factor do these batteries have? Are they cylindrical or "pouch" cells?

Comment: Please start each sentence with capital letter.

Comment: Yes, please do match the capacity (mAh) of all three batteries and always charge all three of them. Don’t mix batteries of different capacities and state-of-charge unless you really know what you are doing.